# Spanish Interest Rates pre-1973

Tags: interest-rate, data

Does anyone know where I can find data on any Spanish interest rates (legal, interbank, t-bill, money market etc.) pre-1973? Bank of Spain, IMF, World Bank, and FRED seem to only go back to 1973 at the very earliest...